# AWS lambda cannot access shared folder?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The following C# code of a lambda to access a Windows shared

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("\\Server\Shared");
```

got the error of

> Could not find a part of the path '/var/task/\\Server\Shared'

Comment: Is `/var/task/\\Server\Shared'` a valid path in Linux?

Comment: no, but `/var/task///Server/Shared` is not right neither.

Comment: What is the right path you should be using?

Comment: It's a windows sharing, the full Windows sharing path is `\\Server\Shared` - shared folder `Shared` of server `Server`.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that Lambda containers would be able to access files from a Windows share.

Comment: SharpCifs.Std appears to be a .Net Core compatible library that may work for you. Have a look at http://sharpcifsstd.dobes.jp/ and the GitHub project page https://github.com/zinkpad/SharpCifs